# How to create a Material with multiple colors animated on Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new on Unity and I would like to create neons tube and a `Material` with multiple colors animation moving on the mesh.

Here is my real neon which is basically what I'm asking here :

[image]

I would like to apply the material on tube but also on cube etc...

How can I create this kind of material ?
Thanks for help on this

Comment: You should look at Shaders. Search Unity Neon shader i'm sure you'll find what you want